# how ot remove an icon in icomoon from a set

Tags: svg, fonts, icons, icon-fonts

I just added a new set of icons but saw that some are duplicated. I couldn't find a function to remove the duplicates. The only way to clean up I found is to

1. select all other icons (which are a lot) and try to find and unselect the duplicates
2. export this new set
3. remove the old set
4. import the new set

Is there an easier way?

Thanks

Comment: What program or programming language are you using?

Comment: ah, sorry, should have included a link as it's just about the online tool: https://icomoon.io/app/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the right button. Didn't see the toolbar on top right next to the "Import icons" button. that's where it is.